# Subdivide a circle according to a subdivided segment

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

Given a segment $AB$, subdivided in $m$ sub-segments, I have to draw a circumference $C$, subdivided in $m$ arcs, in such a way that the ratios between the lengths of the sub-segments of $AB$ are the same as the ratios between the lengths of the arcs subdividing $C$.

Here's an (illustrative) example with $m=3$.
[image]

> **Is there a simple geometric construction to solve this problem?**

I apologize in case this is an obvious question. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: No, not for a general number of equal segments (and not more generally).  Any line segment can be equally subdivided into $m\ge 1$ equal segments, but in dividing a circle into equal arcs only special numbers of them can be constructed geometrically ([a famous result by Gauss tells which numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compass-and-straightedge_construction#Constructible_angles)).

Comment: @hardmath Thanks for your comment! Any chance with $m=3$?

Comment: @hardmath Sorry, I check your link first. Thanks again for your observation!

Comment: As you illustrate, the case of equal subsegments and $m=3$ can be done, but if you were to allow *unequal* subsegments, already the case $m=2$ would be intractable by ruler and compass constructions.  Perhaps you have in mind a more general geometric "construction"?

Comment: The problem, in my case, is to transform a segment of length $c\in\mathbb{N}$, subdivided in $m=3$ segments (e.g. the red, the green and the blue one) of integer lengths (say, $c=\alpha+\beta+\gamma$, $\alpha,\beta,\gamma\in\mathbb{N}$), in the equivalent "wheel of fortune": This wheel should be subdivided in $c$ equal sectors, $\alpha$ of which are red, $\beta$ green and $\gamma$ blue.

Comment: But if the problem is the initial subdivision in $c$ parts, then it is unfeasible, I guess.

Comment: I though it could have been done easily by compass and ruler. Sorry.

Comment: It is feasible when $c$ is one of Gauss's special numbers, which have a prime factorization related to Fermat primes.  I'll see if there is a previous Question which lays out the details, and if not I'll write something up for you.

Comment: @hardmath Thank you very much!!!!